# How to create random drag and drop area in specified area like square

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm working on a project where i have cube like image. In this image i have positions where i have circles, which are basically drop zones.

I can create circles in cascading style sheets and position them absolute inside the relative container on those circles, but this is how we do it every time. But i was checking is there would be some other way to do this logic.

The circles which i mean is a drag & Drop area. Please let me know, if any have any alternative ideas.

I was thinking of the following ways SVG, image map, Canvas etc, but did not tried out any thing.

Thanks
PCA

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand and would greatly benefit from a code example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your question is too broad and the best approach is subject to opinion.  You could use HTML+CS, SVG, or Canvas for this.